# Jenkins: gradle is not being recognized during build

Tags: jenkins

I already installed grade and set up in the environment variable **PATH**

even I am getting an error.

**gradle.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command in Jenkins**

the configuration is

[image]

and the workspace is like [image]

and the default task is in build.gradle is

```
task build{
  dependsOn copyDocsSetup
}
```

while I am building using Jenkin I am getting an error like the below

```
Started by user ajay
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ARS BUILD
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[ARS BUILD] $ cmd.exe /C "gradle.bat -b '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ARS BUILD\gradleBuildScript\BuildARSSystem\ARSBuild\build.gradle"' && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
'gradle.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

how to solve it, I am very new in Jenkins world.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I have installed gradle and added in path in System Environment variable not in user environment variable.
And it's working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a Gradle installation in your global Jenkins configuration should fix your problem.

But a better solution is to use the Gradle wrapper. See the [relevant section on the Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) in the Gradle User Guide for how to configure it. The Gradle wrapper will automatically download the correct Gradle version, so you don't have to install one yourself on the Jenkins machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradle Wrapper in your project.
[image]